# postgresql uuid-ossp.control file missing in extention folder. I have installed postgres 9.6 on windows 10

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am getting the below error on running this query CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

SQLSTATE[58P01]: Undefined file: 7 ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program File
s/2ndQuadrant/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory (SQL:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp")

Comment: Your installation doesn't seem to have come with support for uuid-ossp.  How did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: I cant find the link also to download uuid related files. I'm thinking to upgrade the version to 12.3.2 that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Possible answer, though it is for 9.3: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/234327/164954

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I found it when I had a similar problem.

To install the `uuid-ossp` extension, you need to have some extra modules installed on the server you're on.
You can get those modules by installing `postgresql-contrib`, for example, on a Red Hat server, you'd do

`sudo yum install postgresql-contrib`

Also, note that if you need specific Postgres versions of the modules, you can do something like:

`sudo yum install postgresql13-contrib`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the first answer solved it for me.

Probably you are missing modules.

`sudo yum install postgresql-contrib` and try again.

Comment: OP asked about Windows